# ${session.executionRootDirectory} is not recognized by sonar-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, sonar-maven-plugin

I have several levels of nested Maven projects, where every module can participate in the global integration tests. To have a global, multi module coverage, I've configured jacoco to use and share the same file accross modules, using the Maven variable `${session.executionRootDirectory}`:

```
<execution>
    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <propertyName>jacoco.failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
        <destFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

This way, the same data file is used by each module, no matter how deep it is nested in the submodules. I've checked, a correct data file is generated by jacoco when launching "mvn clean install".

Now the problem appears when launching `mvn sonar:sonar`. It seems that the plugin can not replace that variable with the real path. I can see the following in the logs

```
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /home/tomcat/.jenkins/jobs/MYJOB/workspace/${session.executionRootDirectory}/target/jacoco-it.exec
```

It doesn't work better when using `@{session.executionRootDirectory}`.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [a comment in this bug report at SonarSource](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-3427), advising to use the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-sonar.jacoco.reportPath</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <rawProperties>
                    sonar.jacoco.itReportPath = ${session.executionRootDirectory}/target/jacoco-it.exec
                </rawProperties>
                <addDollar>true</addDollar>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

... which was unfortunately not compatible with Maven 3.1+, I've used and built from sources [that fork](https://github.com/jboesl/maven-plugins), and then I was able to make everything work correctly with Maven 3.2.3.